# Arrows in table are not straight

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

[image]

The arrows in my table are not straight. How can I make them straight?

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table*}[htb]
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|ll|c:c|c|}\cline{1-5}
    \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{… }} &
    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ …}\\\cline{3-5} 
    
                    &  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textsc{..}}  &  & {\textsc{..}}    \\ \cline{1-5} 
                    &   &   ……   &     \\ 
    
    \leftpointright &  … &  \tikzmark{aa}  $ 1,2 $ \tikzmark{a}   & $ 3,4 $ \tikzmark{b}  & \tikzmark{cc} $ 5,6 $ \tikzmark{c}      \\  &     &     &    &       \\\cline{1-5}
                    &    &   …    & ….  &       \\
    \leftpointright &   …   &  \tikzmark{dd} $  7,8,9,10$ \tikzmark{d}  &  $ 11,12 $ \tikzmark{e}  &  \tikzmark{ff} $ 0 $  \tikzmark{f}   \\
                    &    &    &  &          \\ \cline{1-5} 
    \end{tabular}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=0.5pt, shorten <=0.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=.8\baselineskip}]
      \draw [->] ([yshift=.1pt]{pic cs:b}) -- ({pic cs:cc});
       \draw [->] ([yshift=.1pt]{pic cs:e}) -- ({pic cs:ff});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=0.5pt, shorten <=5.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=.8\baselineskip}]
      \draw [->] ([yshift=.95pt]{pic cs:aa}) -- ({pic cs:dd});
       \draw [->] ([yshift=.95pt]{pic cs:c}) -- ({pic cs:f});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, shorten >=0.5pt, shorten <=0.5pt, transform canvas={yshift=-.5\baselineskip}]
       \draw [->] ([yshift=.1pt]{pic cs:a}) -- ({pic cs:cc});
         \draw [->] ([yshift=.1pt]{pic cs:d}) -- ({pic cs:ff});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please, always provide MWE (Minimal Working Example), a small but complete document which can be compile as it is and which reproduce your problem.

Comment: I ask you for complete code  for MWE, If you provide it, we can reproduce image ... BTW, your code fragment has undefined commands etc., so we need to se relevant part of preamble ... (if they may be defined there ...)

Comment: Basically, you will need points like `({pic cs:d} |- {pic cs:ff})` which is directly above or below (pic cs:d) and directly beside (pic cs:ff).

Comment: Any news? Does received answer fulfill your expectation? If yes, you may consider to accept it (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer).

Answer (score 6):

As starting point:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\usepackage{tabularray}


\begin{document}
\tikzset{is/.style = {inner sep=2pt}}
\begin{tblr}{hlines, 
             vline{1,2, 4,5}=solid, vline{3}=dashed,
             colspec = {l*{3}{Q[c,m]}},
             row{1,2}= {rowsep=1pt},
             row{3,4}= {rowsep=5pt},
             }
\SetCell[r=2]{c}
    &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    \dots
        &   &                                       \\
?   & \textsc{..}
        &   & \textsc{..}                           \\ 
?   & \tikzmarknode[is]{a}{$1,2$}   
        & \tikzmarknode[is]{b}{$3,4$}
            & \tikzmarknode[is]{c}{$5,6$}           \\
?   & \tikzmarknode[is]{d}{$7,8,9,10$}
        & \tikzmarknode[is]{e}{$11,12$}
            & \tikzmarknode[is]{f}{$0\vphantom{,}$} \\
\end{tblr}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, 
                    shorten >=0.5pt, shorten <=0.5pt]
                    ]
\draw [->] (d.west |- a) -- (d.west);
\draw [->] (b.east) -- (c.west);
\draw [->] (a.south east) -- (c.south west);

\draw [->] (c.east) -- (f -| c.east);
\draw [->] (e.east) -- (f.west);
\draw [->] (d.south east) -- (f.south west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]