# Arrows in table from one cell to another using table

Tags: tables, tikz-arrows

I want to draw a red arrow from one cell in a table to another.  Linking the descriptions in this case with the units  I have used  table and tabular, and don't want to use  matrix. I am using the exam class. I have many of these tables to write for the answer keys.

MWE

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{array}% this is need to centre data
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{80pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
% this is symbols representing meaning in relation to measurement contexts
\hline
Length of a classroom    &  cm \\ %\rule{0pt}{10pt}
%\\ % this needs to put in otherwise next line will be indented
\hline
Length of a finger nail  &  m  \\ %\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\hline
Length of your shoe  &  mm   \\ %\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you provide a sketch how you imagine where is your arrow (where it start and where it end)?

Comment: Apologies, Zarko, from the end of the word to the beginning of the unit, PS, how do I draw a sketch and upload to website

Comment: Or somewhere suitable in the one cell  to somewhere suitable in another cell

Comment: Check, if the `tikzmark` package can help you. As starting point may serve https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638973/arrows-in-table-are-not-straight/638986#638986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in above comment, you can try with `tikzmark` library, similarly as is done in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/638973):

```
\documentclass[12pt,addpoints]{exam}
\usepackage{array}% this is need to centre data
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}

\usepackage{tikz}           % <---
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}   % <---


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{80pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{5}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-4pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
% this is symbols representing meaning in relation to measurement contexts
\hline
Length of a \tikzmarknode{a}{classroom}                 % <---
        &  \tikzmarknode{b}{cm} \\                      % <---
%\\ % this needs to put in otherwise next line will be indented
\hline
Length of a finger nail  &  m  \\ %\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\hline
Length of your shoe  &  mm   \\ %\rule{0pt}{10pt}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
                    shorten >=2pt, shorten <=2pt]
                    ]
\draw [red, very thick, ->] (a) -- (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

After two or more compiling result of above MWE is:

[image]

Comment: Really do appreciate the quick response, all the other explanations too complicated